# getting "NULL" instead of null in Json response in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest, objectmapper

I have my own object when there is no value it is coming as "NULL" in a string from downstream and it is failing while converting to java object in ObjectMapper

```
class Test 
private String value1; 
private String value2; 
.... getters and setters.
```

Json Response is

```
{"Test": "NULL"}
```

How I can handle this in java
Error message is :

** error : com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.test.Test` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('NULL') **

This is how I am converting json to java

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = getDownstreamResponse(id);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Test test =  mapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), Test.class);
```

Comment: ObjectMapper are related to your get/set and constructor methods since thats how they scan the fields and possibilities. In this case the defined json-string (response) does not match the object at the top so it can not be mapped correct. You need to make sure that it can be built with all information being present and also for ignoring null values, etc.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227224/how-to-check-on-field-in-json-for-null

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to parse the response (and not only the property Test)?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I have updated the post could you please check that.

Comment: Where is that JSON coming from? It's clearly a string field that has the value "NULL", not a _null_/empty value. Thus, trying to parse it as a class with multiple fields cannot work. That is, there's a mismatch between the JSON and what you're expecting.

Comment: actually I am having big payload and one of the value of object is coming as "NULL" in string anyways I need to handle this scenario and parse the other value in response and make this Test as null @dbreaux

Comment: The string "NULL" is not a JSON "empty" value. If you can't get that JSON changed, you're going to have to parse it as a string and manually compare it to "NULL". (I just saw Matteo's answer, which does this. I still say the JSON doesn't seem "correct", but if it's out of your control, that's the approach you'll have to take.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the body of:

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = getDownstreamResponse(id);
```

... you will have:

```
{"Test": "NULL"}
```

... but that's not a `Test.class`. The `Test.class`, eventually, it's only the value of the key `"Test"`, so the following line of code would fail anyway even if the response was correct:

```
Test test =  mapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), Test.class);
```

To make it simpler, I'd do this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode fullResponse = mapper.readTree(responseEntity.getBody());
JsonNode testNode = fullResponse.get("Test");
if ("NULL".equals(testNode.asText())) {
    //you won't be able to parse the response into class Test.class. 
    //do what you wish to do here (throw an exception, return null etc.)
}
Test test =  mapper.readValue(testNode, Test.class);
//here you should have parsed test, so do what you want with it
```